# Call a function inside a for loop in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I've found a lot of information about calling functions inside loops but I haven't discovered anything dealing with Google Apps Script.  I've been through several tutorials and based my code on this: http://tobyho.com/2011/11/02/callbacks-in-loops/ .

My real script pulls data from a Fusion Table and puts it in a Google Doc.  I'm trying to replace some of the Fusion Table numerical data with actual names, but I need a function to run inside the loop for it to work.  Here's a simplified scenario that is giving me the same issues.

```
    var big = [];
    var data = [["fname1", "lname1", 2, 1980],["fname2", "lname2", 3, 1989]];

    function loop() {
      for(i in data) {
        Logger.log(big[i] = changeData(data[i][2]));
    }
    }

    function changeData(n) {
      return function() {
        Logger.log(n + "this worked");
      };
    }
```

When I check the logs I get this twice: function () { Logger.log(n + "this worked");}

Rather than execute the function, it's just returning the text.  I'm really new to javascript and Google Apps script.  Is this a GAS issue or is my code way off?  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: this is expected behaviour. remove `return function() { ... `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The changeData function you have is declaring a function and returning the new function.

You just need to return the results of the changeData function

```
function changeData(n) {      
    Logger.log(n + "this worked"); 
    return "changed data result";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  When I do this, the changeData Log works, but the Log from the loop function comes back 'undefined'.  That's what set me searching for the function in a function solution.  Here's the GAS script: [link](https://script.google.com/d/1eAW3BTV1ElkyMndP3OOxp2UdOMCMzUTroZxWq9IYQRSeDK8qi1hutoDr/edit).  Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What's in your `big` array once the loop has run?

Comment: Just checked your GAS link, you aren't returning anything from your changeData function, try 
`    function changeData(n) {
        return n + " this worked";    
    }`

Comment: Man I feel stupid now.  I was making this much too difficult.  Thanks for the help.